# Need help building MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-match-all

So I have a table with columns:

```
deck_id, card_name, quantity, board(irrelevent for this question)
```

Each row has a deck id which is what I need, a card name, and amount of aforementioned cards.

It would look something like this:

```
101, "cardofblahblah", 3, "main"
101, "differentcard", 2, "main"
102, "cardofblahblah", 1, "main"
102, "fictionalcard", 3, "main"
102, "madeupcard", 4, "main"
103, "magicalcard", 2, "main"
103, "trickcard", 3, "main"
...
...
```

So that's what my database looks like.  What I need is a select query that will return a deck id of a deck which contains all the cards I specify, for example: I need a deck which contains 1 copy of "madeupcard", and 3 copies of "cardofblahblah".  That's what I really need done, but it would be great if someone would also mention how I can do > or < instead of only just setting the amount.

I know how to do the queries, but writing a complex one like this has me stumped.

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.'

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I'm looking for deck id's of decks that contain ALL cards that I specify.  For example, "which decks contain 3 copy of cardofblahblah AND 1 copy of madeupcard?"

Any kind of output where I can get the deck id's is good.  The getting the deck id's is the primary concern for me.

EDIT2:
I figured out the solution after going through various other topics on SO.  However, I may not have the most efficient query, so if someone would improve it, that would be great.

```
SELECT table1.deck_id, table2.deck_id FROM decklist AS table1 
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM decklist WHERE card_name = "cardofblahblah" AND quantity = 3) 
    AS table2 ON table1.deck_id = table2.deck_id 
    WHERE table1.card_name = "madeupcard" AND quantity = 1;"
```

EDIT3:
Thanks to Telarian.  He gave me a better query.

```
SELECT  t.deck_id
FROM    decklist t
INNER JOIN  decklist l
    ON  l.deck_id = t.deck_id
WHERE   (t.card_name = "madeupcard" AND t.quantity >= 1)
        AND
        (l.card_name = "cardofblahblah" AND l.quantity >= 3)
```

Comment: atleast try and get back here when you didn't get anything...

Comment: See the `sql-match-all` tag, which I have added to your question.  This type of question has been answered many times.

Comment: The >= operator can, of course, be changed out for any other operator you might like. It seems likely though, that that is the one you would want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is being way over-complicated...

Won't the following query give you what you want?

```
SELECT  t.deck_id
FROM    decklist t
    INNER JOIN  decklist l
        ON  l.deck_id = t.deck_id
WHERE   (t.card_name = "madeupcard" AND t.quantity >= 1)
        AND
        (l.card_name = "cardofblahblah" AND l.quantity >= 3)
```

Comment: No, that seems to give me all decks with "madeupcard" and/or "cardofblahblah".  I need all decks with both only.

Comment: Good call on the comparison operator ypercube.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you're wrong. It does not show decks with "madeupcard" and/or "cardofblahblah". It only shows decks with both "madeupcard" and "cardofblahblah".

Comment: I should point out that if there were a chance of finding a card name more than once per deck (which I doubt is the case in this situation) then you would need to add DISTINCT to the query to ensure you didn't return a deck multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken.  You're right, I made a mistake while inputting the query.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm a bit new to Stackoverflow, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ((board='madeupcard' AND quantity=1) OR (board='cardofblahblah' AND quantity=3))
```

Let me know if this is what you want...

Comment: Not exactly.  I need deck id's for decks that contain ALL of the cards listed.  The one you created will show rows of decks that contain any of them, I need rows shown from decks that contain BOTH "madeupcard" AND "cardofblahblah".

Comment: please update question accordingly.. Also provide what input will be and output you are expected...